# What should I write down to avoid a stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

so I'm currently working on a fibonacci code via recursive function.

```
package blatt4;

public class BigIntegerFibonacci
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x;
        System.out.println(fib_basic(5));

    }

    public static int fib_basic(int x)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        int i = fib_basic(x - 1 ) + fib_basic(x -2);
        return i;
    }
```

if I do it like this I'll get a stackoverflow error but when im putting *if (x == 0 || x == 1); return 1;* this code is okay and it shows me the result as I wanted it. Can someone please explain why? I know there is a way to not include x == 1 within a recursive function. But I really don't remember how to write it down.

Comment: You recurse for x-1 and x-2, so you need two lowest-value cases without recursion.`if (x <= 1)` would do 0 and 1, so fib(2) ends, and hence all terminate.

Answer (score 2):

Because here

```
int i = fib_basic(x - 1 ) + fib_basic(x -2);
```

When `x` is 1, you call your function as `fib_basic(-1)` in the second invocation, which then has nothing to stop the function from recursing (since `x` will never be 0 from then on) and you enter an infinite loop.

Comment: I just found out what caused the problem thanks to you!